# PROBLEMAS CON FETCH CORS Y LOS HEADERS

Tags: javascript, fetch, cors

estoy intentando usar fetch para recibir los datos de una pagina. Pero siempre me devuelve error de CORS, excepto si pongo el modo en NO-CORS que me devuelve una respuesta opaca, que no me sirve de nada.

Que estoy haciendo mal? aparte de todo ;), la verdad que soy muy nuevo con Javascript y no tengo mucha idea. En php pones los headers arriba y funcionando....

La idea es hacerlo todo con javascript. Ni php ni ajax ni nada. Es posible????

Mil gracias

```
    function getCovid(){
    const url="https://datos.comunidad.madrid/catalogo/dataset/7da43feb-8d4d-47e0-abd5-3d022d29d09e/resource/877fa8f5-cd6c-4e44-9df5-0fb60944a841/download/covid19_tia_muni_y_distritos_s.json";
fetch(url,
{    
    //mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
}).then(
    response=>{
        console.log(response);
        
    }
    );  
}
getCovid();
```

El error que me devuelve es este:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://datos.comunidad.madrid/catalogo/dataset/7da43feb-8d4d-47e0-abd5-3d022d29d09e/resource/877fa8f5-cd6c-4e44-9df5-0fb60944a841/download/covid19_tia_muni_y_distritos_s.json' from origin 'https://pruebasxibo.000webhostapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
pruebasjs.js:7 GET https://datos.comunidad.madrid/catalogo/dataset/7da43feb-8d4d-47e0-abd5-3d022d29d09e/resource/877fa8f5-cd6c-4e44-9df5-0fb60944a841/download/covid19_tia_muni_y_distritos_s.json net::ERR_FAILED
getCovid @ pruebasjs.js:7
(anonymous) @ pruebasjs.js:29
pruebajava.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
Promise.then (async)
getCovid @ pruebasjs.js:18
(anonymous) @ pruebasjs.js:29
```

Comment: Esa URL resulta en un error 404.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo acabo de comprobar y no devuelve 404. He accedido y ha devuelto un array de JSONs.

Comment: @Sergio Garrido Domínguez ese json es el que quiero traerme para tratarlo... Pero no sé si solo con fetch es posible

Comment: Son datos libres de la comunidad de Madrid sobre la.incidencia del covid

Comment: Hmm el tema es que parece que esa url no tiene un certificado SSL válido.. por lo cual fetch lo rechaza. Tipical it spanish

Comment: Pero aún así, si metiera los headers debería funcionar no? O solo voy a poder hacerlo por XMLHttpRequest??

Answer (score 0):

El tema de los CORS es algo complicado en mi opinión, y aun no lo entiendo del todo. Por lo que entiendo, es para evitar que cualquiera pueda hacer peticiones a diestra y siniestra, es por esto que tienes que tener tu pagina montada en un servidor y en ese caso, los CORS no debería suponer un error, pero si trabajas en local, este siempre tiene problemas.

Todo esto esta detallado en la documentación de Cross-Origin Resource Sharing:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Que solución te puedo dar por el momento, utilizar la API cors-anywhere. Esta es una API montada en heroku que toma tu URL y hace la petición por ti y te devuelve el resultado.

La manera de usarlo seria la siguiente:

```
const corsAnywhere = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

const yourUrl =
    'datos.comunidad.madrid/catalogo/dataset/7da43feb-8d4d-47e0-abd5-3d022d29d09e/resource/877fa8f5-cd6c-4e44-9df5-0fb60944a841/download/covid19_tia_muni_y_distritos_s.json';

fetch(corsAnywhere + yourUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }),
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Con esto podrás usar la API sin problemas.
Tambien te dejo un hilo de SO donde se habla sobre el tema:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670703/how-to-use-cors-anywhere-to-reverse-proxy-and-add-cors-headers

La pagina oficial de cors-anywhere:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Por último aclarar que esta no es la solución definitiva, cuando estés en producción deberías volver a iterar sobre esta problemática, pero al menos puedes seguir trabajando con la API

Comment: Me gustarái eliminar la dependencia de terferos, pero es cierto que así funciona correctamente, esta respuesta la habia encontrado, pero no habia sido capaz de hacerla funcionar,  hay que seguir buscando pero no se por donde continuar... pero esta claro que es el certificado de la pagina.

Comment: Después de hacer unas pruebas la mejor forma sin duda es usar cors-anywhere... La única cosa que se me ocurre es que el certificado de mi hosting no sea totalmente correcto. Pero así queda solucionado... Mil gracias Ignacio